# Import phantom wallet private key into solana CLI

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I need to use a Phantom Wallet through the Solana CLI, but I'm unable to configure it.

For example, to check balance using

```sh
solana balance --keypair fileexportedfromphantom
```

but can't read the info.

How do I convert that private key into a valid form for use in Solana CLI?

Comment: my private key was serie of byte numbers like 53,63,65 but problem was i had to put them in phantom extension including the brackets [] then it worked

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try:

`solana-keygen recover 'prompt://?key=0/0' -o <file.json>`

And enter the 24-word recovery phrase from Phantom under "Show Secret Recovery Phrase".

This is because Phantom uses the `0/0` derivation path for wallets and needs the extra provided path to get to the correct account.

You can use the same command with `1/0`, `2/0` ... `N/0` to get the different Phantom derived accounts.

See here for more info about hierarchical derivation with the Solana tools: https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#hierarchical-derivation

Or use the Solflare wallet to check the derivation paths for your particular 24 word phrase here: https://solflare.com/access

---

As per the recent comment from @FutForFut, this assumes you have or want to use the Secret Recovery Phrase from Phantom. In certain cases, you might only have the private key from Phantom ("Show Private Key") in menus. This is a base58 encoded key, and you'll need to convert that into a byte-array in a JSON file.

Here's the Javascript snippet, using the `bs58` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58):

```js
const bs58 = require('bs58');
const fs = require('fs');
b = bs58.decode('privatekeyexportedfromphantom');
j = new Uint8Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset, b.byteLength / Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
fs.writeFileSync('key.json', `[${j}]`);
```

Update fields `privatekeyexportedfromphantom` and `key.json` as required.

Comment: One non-obvious thing about Phantom: If you use the secret recovery phrase, as suggested in this answer, anyone who has that recovery phrase will be able to construct the private keys for ALL accounts in that wallet. I suspect the more common use case is to just get ONE special account/wallet imported into the Solana CLI. In that case, Jon C's answer is more appropriate, and more secure since it will only expose one keypair, not the whole sequence of derived (or derivable keypairs).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the alternative method to this answer also.

Comment: Made a replit https://replit.com/@therealsuji/Phantom-Private-Key-to-Keypair?v=1

Answer (score 14):

It's a bit annoying, but you'll have to decode the base-58 private key returned by Phantom into an array of bytes.  Here's a simple Python code snippet to accomplish this, using the `base58` package (https://pypi.org/project/base58/):

```py
import base58
byte_array = base58.b58decode(MY_PRIVATE_KEY_IN_BASE58)
json_string = "[" + ",".join(map(lambda b: str(b), byte_array)) + "]"
print(json_string)
```

You can pipe that output to a file, and then use that as your `--keypair` with the CLI tools.

Comment: Error: could not read keypair file . If i use solana-keygen new, to generate a key it's showed like a combinations of numbers. The output generated using your script is binary

Comment: I get something like this [�,[,:,�,�,>,�,L,=,�,J,�, and this is the expected look: [157,179,177,192,112,

Comment: Strange, I just tested this again myself and it works.  For `MY_PRIVATE_KEY_IN_BASE58`, you're supposed to put in a string, e.g.
 `"4AfmonCVDRutyt3vMfsooagRsoNXTCVURGZ7nzSZPP9CWykXUmgA72Sfgrne7EcqtVJE6Gq6aA8xw21bHtbZMQzL"`
which gives
 `[158,99,132,43,140,119,254,9,6,225,141,208,225,184,48,219,246,115,45,3,0,67,160,190,25,199,130,208,179,210,219,1,41,32,144,228,51,198,235,65,64,71,155,119,235,189,157,49,2,65,230,165,161,159,153,77,213,153,226,174,35,2,212,89]`

Can you test that?  This is running with python 3.8 on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Exactly the same fails for me

Comment: works for me, run simple python script in terminal or repl.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair trying to understand the difference between Phantom wallet private key and a 32-byte private key

Comment: It worked for me, I am just wondering why it converts to base 10 upon using string()?

Comment: Don't forget to `pip3 install base58`...

Answer (score 0):

here's a little python 3 script to take in your private key, and output it to the solana configuration directory

```
from pathlib import Path

import base58

SAVE_DIR = Path.home() / '.config' / 'solana'


def convert_key():
    byte_array = base58.b58decode(input('Enter Public Key: '))
    return "[" + ",".join(map(lambda b: str(b), byte_array)) + "]"


def create_file(save_dir: Path, key_name: str) -> Path:
    keypair_path = save_dir / f'{key_name}.json'
    if not SAVE_DIR.exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError('Solana config directory not found')
    if not SAVE_DIR.is_dir():
        raise NotADirectoryError('Solana config directory not found')
    if keypair_path.exists():
        raise FileExistsError('Keypair already exists')
    return keypair_path


def main():
    keypair = input('Enter keypair name: ')
    keypair_path = create_file(SAVE_DIR, keypair)
    keypair_path.write_text(convert_key())
    print(f'Keypair {keypair} created at {keypair_path}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```