# Restoring Solana wallet in CLI from mnemonic

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I am looking to restore my Solana CLI wallet from the mnemonic. The ID.json file was overwritten so I only have the seed phrase. It doesnt provide the same address when imported into phantom or sollet. Is there a command to do this or how can I restore my wallet?

Comment: Might be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245982/import-phantom-wallet-private-key-into-solana-cli ?

Comment: @JonC I think so - 'It doesnt provide the same address when imported into phantom or sollet' makes me think it's referring to HD wallet addresses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import phantom wallet private key into solana CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245982/import-phantom-wallet-private-key-into-solana-cli)

Answer (score 3):

Sure! From the [How to restore a Keypair from a mnemonic phrase](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase):

```
solana-keygen recover
```

There's also TypeScript and CLI examples in the [Solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-check-if-a-public-key-has-an-associated-private-key)